Send Get data with <a href="?key=value"> when there is already other GET data on the page
I am looking to change the language of a webpage with this:
<div class="login_button"><a href="?lang=fr">FR</a> | <a href="?lang=de">DE</a></div>

And it works fine with PHP when I receive the GET request like this:
if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == "GET" && isset($_GET['lang'])){
    $_SESSION['language'] = strval($_GET['lang']);
}

While the website link looks like this:
localhost:/mywebsite/courses.php?lang=fr

but I get into trouble when there is already other GET requests on the same page like
localhost:/mywebsite/courses.php?courseid=54

because when I change the language it removes the courseid key and the expected DB values are not found, and it gives logically plenty of errors.
I thought about saving the courseid values into session variables so if the language is changed I can make conditions and act accordingly, or sending post requests with forms.
What would be the best approach. Any other ideas?
I am looking to know if I can append & of there is already some data with ?key=value with a href
Thanks

Edit (Answer to own problem here): there is this link here where it states this:
$query = parse_url($url, PHP_URL_QUERY);

// Returns a string if the URL has parameters or NULL if not
if ($query) {
    $url .= '&lang=';
} else {
    $url .= '?lang=';
}

but it actually needed some changes otherwise the more we click on a href the more it adds &lang=..&lang=.. etc. And to me it was unclear how it worked. I realised thanks to AbraCadaver and ADyson, one needs to check about the url first with PHP, then we need to control where the variables a href="< ? php # Control the output here ? >" will lead to. So here is my working code. I thought I would still give an example on how it could be.
In the header i retrieve the url of my website:
$url = (empty($_SERVER['HTTPS']) ? 'http' : 'https') . "://$_SERVER[HTTP_HOST]$_SERVER[REQUEST_URI]";
$query = parse_url($url, PHP_URL_QUERY);
if (($query != null)) {
    if(!str_contains($query, 'lang=')){
        $url .= '&lang=';
    }else{
        
        $search = array("lang=de", "lang=fr");
        $replace   = "lang=";
        $url = str_replace($search, $replace, $url);
    }
} else {
    $url .= '?lang=';
}

Than, later in the HTML code I have this:
<div class="login_button">
    <a href="<?php echo $url;?>fr" class ="active" style="display:inline-block;">FR</a> | 
    <a href="<?php echo $url;?>de "style="display:inline-block;">DE</a>
</div>


This is not an exact duplicate of the "Manipulate a url string by adding GET parameter" because What I am taking about is happening before we receive the data with PHP

The Basic Method in  that post is what you need.  Check to see if there are already parameters and add them and yours.

Ok I build the url with php, but how do I actually change this url?

Apply the basic method from the accepted answer in the duplicate. This needs to happen when you're building the URL to go into your <a href="?lang=fr">FR</a> link so it it includes not only the lang=fr bit but also any parameters which were already in the current URL - this ensures they're persisted into the next URL/request when the user clicks to change the language. Get the current URL, with its parameters (if any), append the lang=fr bit to it, and then stick that generated URL into the href of the link. Demo: https://3v4l.org/oFq9E

Ok thanks a lot for your help. I actually didn't understand that it had to be in the header and be integrated in the a href before the user clicks. That makes perfectly sense. I just needed to correct something in your code because with your demo, if I don't check for lang= the next link will just append lang=de&lang=fr&lang=fr&lang=de.... the more I click

It's not really my demo, I just took it from the link. But yes you're right if the use case can involve multiple clicks then you would certainly need to check what's already there before acting. Glad you found a workable solution
